# How do i resize UIView with respect to ratio on dragging the corner edges?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiview

I have a UIView with some size. And i am resizing that view on button clicked. But resizing of  UIView is depends on the ratio like 3:2 , 4:3 , 16: 9 . And than the dragging of the UIView must be done according to the ratio.

kResizeThumbSize 30

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
  {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

  if ([((UIView *)(touch.view)) isEqual:canvas])
    {
        touchStart = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:canvas];
        isResizingLR = (canvas.bounds.size.width - touchStart.x < kResizeThumbSize && canvas.bounds.size.height - touchStart.y < kResizeThumbSize);
        isResizingUL = (touchStart.x <kResizeThumbSize && touchStart.y <kResizeThumbSize);
        isResizingUR = (canvas.bounds.size.width-touchStart.x < kResizeThumbSize && touchStart.y<kResizeThumbSize);
        isResizingLL = (touchStart.x <kResizeThumbSize && canvas.bounds.size.height -touchStart.y <kResizeThumbSize);
    }

    if(isResizingLR || isResizingUL|| isResizingLL || isResizingUR){
        [canvas removeGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];
    }
}

- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    CGPoint touchPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:canvas];
    CGPoint previous=[[touches anyObject]previousLocationInView:canvas];

    float  deltaWidth = touchPoint.x-previous.x;
    float  deltaHeight = touchPoint.y-previous.y;

    if (isResizingLR) {
        canvas.frame = CGRectMake(canvas.frame.origin.x, canvas.frame.origin.y,touchPoint.x + deltaWidth, touchPoint.y + deltaWidth);
    }
    if (isResizingUL) {
        canvas.frame = CGRectMake(canvas.frame.origin.x + deltaWidth, canvas.frame.origin.y + deltaHeight, canvas.frame.size.width - deltaWidth, canvas.frame.size.height - deltaHeight);
    }
    if (isResizingUR) {
        canvas.frame = CGRectMake(canvas.frame.origin.x ,canvas.frame.origin.y + deltaHeight,  canvas.frame.size.width + deltaWidth, canvas.frame.size.height - deltaHeight);
    }
    if (isResizingLL) {
        canvas.frame = CGRectMake(canvas.frame.origin.x + deltaWidth ,canvas.frame.origin.y ,  canvas.frame.size.width - deltaWidth, canvas.frame.size.height + deltaHeight);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

Check out which of `deltaWidth` and `deltaHeight` is bigger as an absolute value. It becomes a leading size and is applied to the frame as is. The other one is calculated from the leading size delta according to the ratio and then applied to the frame and the real (smaller) delta is ignored.

You might also need to apply ratio checks in the initial `deltaWidth` agains `deltaHeight`, to better determine which change is bigger.